# how to convert scanned jpg files to pbm format losslessly?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Using `ImageMagick`'s `convert` utility to convert some scanned jpg files to pbm files.

However, even if the option `-quality 100` is used, the pbm's resolution still looks worse than the original scanned jpg file.

Worse, the scanned jpg file is a colored one, while the converted pbm is black and white.

Info of original jpg:
image size: 2256 × 1568 pixels
dpi: 300 pixels/inch
color model: RGB

info of the converted pbm:
image size: 2256 × 1568 pixels
dpi: 72 pixels/inch
color model: Gray

Currently, here is what I did to convert the format:

```
qiang@bonjour:~/scan$ convert scan000.jpg scan000.pbm
```

Am I missing any option to use with `convert`? As I mentioned earlier, `-quality 100` had been tried, but to no avail.

Comment: -quality only applies to writing to jpg. You may lose quality just by decompressing the jpg. Can you post a link to your jpg? Are you comparing the digital image or the printed image? If the latter, you have changed densities, so that may affect any printed result. PBM format is binary, I believe, according to http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pbm.html. Perhaps you want to write to scan000.ppm, if your jpg image is color. If you want to convert from color to grayscale, then perhaps you want `convert image.jpg -colorspace gray image.pgm` or for binary, `convert image.jpg -monochrome image.pbm

Comment: I am comparing digital images, @fmw42. The reason I used pbm format is that I want to convert these scanned images to djvu files in the end. Looks like ppm is not acceptable to `cjb2` command in djvulibre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ImageMagick, I think you want to output to PPM not PBM. Try

```
convert image.jpg image.ppm
```

or try the ascii version by using

```
convert image.jpg -compress none image.ppm
```

PBM is binary (black/white) and PGM is grayscale. If you want to keep color, then you need to use PPM.

Unfortunately, I believe that ImageMagick can only read DJVU format images. So you cannot write to it directly from ImageMagick.

Comment: Looks like the limitation is on the end of `cjb2`, the utility in djvulibre suite to convert pbm/pgm/rle format into single-page djvu files. PBM/PGM are binary or grayscale. I tried to `convert` the jpg file into rle format, and it didn't report any error. However, when I tried to use `cjb2` to convert the rle format file into djvu file, it errored out. Looks like the rle format `convert`ed is not what is expected by `cjb2`. I am stuck now, not sure how to make a djvu file from a full-color scan image.

Comment: After some research, I found that to convert full-color scanned jpg files into single-page djvu files, `c44` is the right tool. It is also in `djvulibre` suite, as is `cjb2`, but `cjb2` is basically for pbm/pgm, no good for full-colored images.

Comment: `cjb2` This is a simple encoder for bitonal files. That means you have to start with an input bitonal (bilevel, black/white) image. So you could use `convert image.jpg -monochrome image.pbm`. But then you lose all the color in your input. Does djvu support color or only black/white bitonal image? If so, you need a different tool from `cjb2`